# Creating 2x2 flex grid with different widths which stack

Tags: css, flexbox

I have been wrestling with `flex` and how to do a simple grid, with different widths, and then to make them stackable in mobile.

```
-------------------
menu  | A1     | B1
      | A2     | B2
--------------------
```

But then, when responsive, stacks to:

```
------------
    A1
------------
    B1
------------
    A2
------------
    B2
```

(the menu becomes a burger already)

So far I have:

```css
.flex-row {
   display: flex;
   flex: 1;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-col {
   margin: 6px;
   padding: 0px;
   background-color: black;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex: 1;
   flex-direction: column;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="sidebar-menu-col">
    menu here
 </div>
 <div class="flex-col">
   <div class="flex-col">A1</div>
   <div class="flex-col">B1</div>
   <div class="flex-col">A2</div>
   <div class="flex-col">B2</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, I cannot get the width to work even when using something like `flex: 0 0 15em;`. In desktop, then things don't look good, and all show up as cols. Wondering how to break it so it's 2x2 on desktop (aside from the menu) and stacked in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using grid instead for this. i have added display grid giving it 2 colums and 2 rows and in media querie for small devices it changes to 1 column and 4 rows..and i dnt understand the class you are targeting in css (.flex-row) as there are no html of that class..? and you shouldnt use same names for parent container and the childrens..

```css
.container {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }

            /* .flex-row {
                display: flex;
                flex: 1;
                flex-direction: row;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            } */
            

            .flex-col-container {
                margin: 6px;
                padding: 0px;
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
                /* display: flex;
                justify-content: center; */
                display: grid;
                
                grid-auto-flow: row;
                grid-template-columns: 15em  5em; /*A1 and a2 is 15em & b1 and b2 is 5em*/
                grid-row: 2em 2em;/*2 rows with height of 2em*/
               

            }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
                .flex-col-container {
                    grid-template-columns: 15em;/*1 column with width of 15em*/
                    grid-row: 2em 2em 2em 2em;/*4 rows with height of 2em*/

                }

            }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar-menu-col">
            menu here
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col-container">
            <div class="flex-col">A1</div>
            <div class="flex-col">B1</div>
            <div class="flex-col">A2</div>
            <div class="flex-col">B2</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Ah, grid is better, yes. Though, how do I make A1 (and A2) wider than B1 and B2? Setting width in %? Let's say 60% for A1 and 40% for B1 within `flex-col-container`? If I mess with `grid-template-columns`, would that do it, but each column would be different width not fixed (like in mobile).  Otherwise, stacks perfectly in mobile!

Comment: i have updated the answer, yes messing grid-template-colunms is right

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution with flex and css-variables. Firstly, I renamed parent the element of the columns for better usability. Then  we create three values for margins, width A and width B. With the`:nth-of-type` pseudo-class and **odd**, **even** arguments we assign the width. The last step, we create a breakpoint (@media) for mobile devices and edit the values A, B.

##### Flextbox solution

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar-menu-col {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-col {
  --margin: 6px;
  --A: 70%;
  --B: 30%;
  margin: var(--margin);
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
}

.flex-col:nth-of-type(odd) {
  flex: 1 0 calc(var(--A) - var(--margin) * 2);
}

.flex-col:nth-of-type(even) {
  flex: 0 1 calc(var(--B) - var(--margin) * 2);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
 .container {
    flex-flow: column;
  }
  .flex-col {
    --margin: 0px;
    --A: 100%;
    --B: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar-menu-col">menu here</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex-col">A1</div>
    <div class="flex-col">B1</div>
    <div class="flex-col">A2</div>
    <div class="flex-col">B2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

##### Grid solution

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar-menu-col {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  --margin: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 70% calc(30% - var(--margin));
  gap: calc(var(--margin) * 2);
  padding: var(--margin);
}

.flex-col {
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .wrapper {
    --margin: 0px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar-menu-col">menu here</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex-col">A1</div>
    <div class="flex-col">B1</div>
    <div class="flex-col">A2</div>
    <div class="flex-col">B2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great but in mobile, how can it stack into rows?

Comment: Do you mean without margins? If you add `--margin: 0px` to **@media** in **.flex-col** class, it will remove margins.